# why i cant change the text of a button from main activity?

Tags: android

I am currently learning Android development for a day only. 
I am following Stanford CS 193A lecture 01: basics and first app from youtube.

My problem is I can not change the text of button from main activity though I am correctly following the video.

```
package com.example.shojib.guessinggame;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void rightnum(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Button right= (Button) findViewById(R.id.rightbtn);
        right.setText("right");
    }
    public void leftnum(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: show your `activity_main.xml`

Comment: your `onCreate` is pretty empty, I think you left out `rightnum()` and `leftnum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your `<Button>` tags include the `android:onClick` attributes, with the names of the methods in your `MainActivity`. For example, you could have:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="left button"
    android:onClick="leftnum"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="right button"
    android:onClick="rightnum"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above code you gave toast ,but if you simply wish to change text on button , go to XML , add text attribute to specific button you want .